# Get name of an artifact in Azure Release Pipelines Task Group

Tags: azure-pipelines

I am working on a release pipeline which consumes an internally published nuget package.

I will have multiple release pipelines which will do the same thing (triggered by various build pipelines), so I want to reuse the steps of the release within a task group.

One of the steps of the task group is `Download Package` and as a parameter it expects the package name.
I don't want to provide the PackageName as a task group parameter, because that's an extra magic string to be configured.

**Since there is always only one artifact, which triggers the release, I would like to get its name and pass it to the task setting.**

I don't see any way to do that, it doesn't seem there's a [built in variable for this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=batch#default-variables---primary-artifact) - closest I get is `RELEASE_PRIMARYARTIFACTSOURCEALIAS`.

Is there any way to achieve that, perhaps with a script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your release pipeline is triggered by build pipeline, so it will take the corresponding build artifact as source artifact, and then there will be a default step `Download Artifacts` to download artifact.

Therefore, it is not needed to download this package again in your task group in release pipeline. See: [Artifact download](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/artifacts?view=azure-devops#artifact-download) for more details.

Comment: Hi Bartosz, Does my answer work? Please check it and kindly let me know the result.

Comment: Hi - not really, something doesn't work OK.
The download task says it succeeded (`Download artifact to: /local/vstsagent/_work/r31/a`) but then when I run `ls -1` on this folder, it seems empty: `ls -1 $SYSTEM_ARTIFACTSDIRECTORY`. returns nothing. When I check, the variable is resolved correctly to the same path: `SYSTEM_ARTIFACTSDIRECTORY is /local/vstsagent/_work/r31/a`

Comment: One thing that should be added (probably obvious, however was not the case in my pipeline) is that the build pipeline must contain a `publish` step.

Comment: Yeah, you need to publish build artifact so that release pipeline can download it.